# How can I alter this to run in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

What needs changing for this to run in postgreSQL?

I was given the piece of sql

```
UPDATE ACC
SET ACC.ACC_EC = SITESmin.ACC_EC, 
    ACC.ACC_NC = SITESmin.ACC_NC
FROM    ACC
       INNER JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT TOP 1
                                *
                      FROM      SITES
                      ORDER BY  ( acc_ec - site_etg ) * ( acc_ec - site_etg ) + (acc_ncb - site_ntg ) * ( acc_ncb - site_ntg )
                ) SITESmin;
```

It seems to be using SET but I do not know why, so if it's not needed drop it.
I am trying to get postgresql to work out distances. For every record in file one I have to compare to 3300  records in file 2 and select the nearest. Received wisdom suggests an array solution for the 3300 but I do not know how to do that. Perhaps it it  a "sub query" in SQL.

If I am permitted to upload samples I will do so, though I have the feeling this is not allowed?

Here are the filed names

```
public.acc.Location_Easting_OSGR 
public.acc.Location_Northing_OSGR
"public"."Sites"."SITE_ETG" 
"public"."Sites"."SITE_NTG"
```

Comment: `s/ACC INNER JOIN LATERAL//`

Comment: And replace `TOP 1` at the top of the subquery by `LIMIT 1` at the bottom. And: add some range table qualifiers to `... acc_ec - site_etg ...` etc, making the query understandable for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH SITESmin as (
    SELECT ACC_EC, ACC_NC
    FROM      SITES
    ORDER BY  ( acc_ec - site_etg ) * ( acc_ec - site_etg ) + (acc_ncb - site_ntg ) * ( acc_ncb - site_ntg )
    LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE ACC
SET ACC.ACC_EC = SITESmin.ACC_EC,
    ACC.ACC_NC = SITESmin.ACC_EC
FROM SITESmin;
```

If it does not work, please provide the schema and some data to make it easier to reproduce

Comment: Thank you Gab, sorry for my delay, had to rebuild everything and I am struggling to import my csv file because of "timestamp" format issues which has stopped me.

Comment: can't edit the op so, if the schema means the field names, these are now called as follows: public.acc.Location_Easting_OSGR and public.acc.Location_Northing_OSGR then "public"."Sites"."SITE_ETG" and "public"."Sites"."SITE_NTG" I'll add a description in the op, maybe I can do that.

Comment: a horse with no name has banned me from editing my opening post, having added the wrong code to it.